# Relative Cell Address needed in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need a **relative** cell address. i.e. "A2" not "$A$2"

When I use `myAddress = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Address`,
myAddress returns $B$2. I actually need the relative value `B2`.

Why, you ask? I knew you would ask... Because I want to then fill down the formula using that `B2` cell address to all of the cells below it. And I don't want each subsequent cell to refer to `B2`, but `C2` then `D2` and so on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
myAddress = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Address(False, False)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this the same as typing .Address(0,0)?

Comment: The effect will be the same, but I would slap anyone on my team for doing this.

Comment: I just found a post on a forum using that as you were posting your answer.This is providing arguments to the Address(RowAbsolute, ColumnAbsolute) parameters correct?

Comment: @GSerg Why? What disagrees with you with .Address(0,0)?

Comment: @phillipsK Because if a parameter accepts a `boolean`, you pass a boolean, not a number that may be converted to a boolean. You can pass `42` instead of `True` to that same method, and it would look just as appropriate. The only thing it achieves is making the next guy think why the hell `42` is passed instead of `True` and whether that actually has some effect different to just passing `True`.

Comment: @GSerg Is it  easier for a computer to interpret numbers or characters/strings?

Comment: @phillipsK A string for a computer is a sequence of bytes (numbers) anyway. However in this example there are no strings to begin with. `False` is not a string, like `"False"` would be. The additional work for the computer here is to detect that the passed [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx) is not of type `VT_BOOL` and call the moral equivalent of `CBool()`.

Comment: The compiler will handle the `False` and `0` as string and define later the type as Boolean value or Number and finally both will be an Integer

Comment: @Blackcat The compiler will absolutely not handle `False` and `0` as strings.

Comment: Ok. i think terminology problem as characters or text or as string of characters

Comment: @Blackcat The the compiler will absolutely not handle `False` and `0` as strings, characters, text or strings of characters.