# Worksheet_Change if not as per list in range then don't do

Tags: vba

Wanted to know code if blank & if not as per list (in range A:A) then don't do anything. And if found in list then `Workbooks.Open`. Can any one guide me with correct code in this case.

My current code is below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "D11" Then

Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E11").Value, ReadOnly:=False, Password:=""

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please specify clearly as to what the query is. Please also specify what you have already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks,
post edited updated

Comment: By default `Target.Address` [will return `$D$11`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24933692/11683).

Comment: So add the dollar signs, or change `.Address` to `.Address(False,False)`

Comment: Actually i did but when D11 will be blank or other than character in A:A then it will still trying to open previous file and tring password

Comment: .address(false,false) not working.

Comment: At the moment I guess your code doesn't do anything as, as @GSerge said, you need to write `If Target.Address = "$D$11" Then`.  Once that's corrected it doesn't matter what you type in `$D$11` it will always open the workbook who's full file path is in cell `E11` on `sheet1`.

Comment: What I think you want to do is validate that the value in cell `$D$11` is a workbook and that the exact same value exists in column A and only then open the workbook?

Comment: Yes actually you got it.

there is validation in D11 and on the same vlookup of file name in E11.

but when i enter wrong value or its blank that time getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a hedper function that tries to open some workbook and returns:

- `False` if unsuccessful o
- `True` if successful along with a valid `Workbook` object reference

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook

    If Target.Address = "$D$11" Then

        If GetWorkBook(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E11").Value, wb) Then
            With wb 'reference just opened workbook

                ' your code to exploit opened workbook

            End With
        End If

    End If

End Sub

Function GetWorkBook(fullname As Variant, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next 'avoid subsequent error stop the function
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fullname, ReadOnly:=False, Password:="") 'try and open a workbook with passed full name
    GetWorkBook = Not wb Is Nothing 'return function result (i.e. 'True' if 'wb is a valid 'Workbook' reference)
End Function
```

Comment: @MaheshJadhav, you are welcome. and please consider marking this answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: @MaheshJadhav, what happened?