# .Address( Relative Reference

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with creating a Formula that will auto-sum a column, and then copy that formula across the two adjacent columns. 
Each month the amount of rows will be different, so I need for it to be Dynamic. The code I am using now returns an absolute reference, 
while I need it to be relative

Current Code:

```
Range("G1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select

'NEED TO MAKE FORMULA RELATIVE
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1).End(xlUp).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")"
Selection.Copy
```

Result: `=SUM($G$1:$G$156)`

All I need is to remove the absolute reference here

Changing the code to:
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Address(0, 0, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1).End(xlUp).Address(0, 0, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ")""`

Will return formula:`"=SUM(M157:M312)`

With the same result while replacing `(0, 0,` with `(false, false,` and `(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False,`

Comment: Why not define a dynamic named range that will determine the number of rows, then use that name in the `SUM`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative Cell Address needed in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933692/relative-cell-address-needed-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Consider using a `Table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Address(False, False) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1).End(xlUp).Address(False, False) & ")"
```